# ArcObjects open an existing memory workspace

Tags: arcobjects, in-memory

With .NET ArcObjects, I discovered that I could use an InMemoryWorkspaceFactory for my temporary feature classes. It is great, but I would like to know if there is a way to open an existing InMemory workspace. If mean, if I create "MyWorkspace" in memory with the following code, is there a way to open it elsewhere without keeping the variable pFeatureWorkspace global?

```
        Dim t As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.InMemoryWorkspaceFactory")
        pWorkspaceFactory = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
        aWorksName = pWorkspaceFactory.Create(Nothing, "MyWorkspace", Nothing, 0)
        pFeatureWorkspace = CType(aWorksName, WorkspaceName).Open()
```

Comment: This problem screams for a static singleton object pattern.

Comment: The workspace factory is a singleton, but the feature workspace is not (at least is it not in the ArcObjects help).

Comment: No, I'm saying that *you* should use the singleton object design pattern to manifest access to the in_memory workspace, not a global.

Comment: Ok, that way, I will use a global variable anyway.